# aubiocut command-line tool splitting the file but export a corrupted files, any suggestions?

Tags: command-line, aubio

I have this command: `aubiocut -i file.mp3 -c -b -o Output`

it is splitting the file on beats basis alright, but the output files is not playing except the firs file

here is a [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0q2xx0yw1kl50nl/1.mp3?dl=0)

The desired result I'm expecting is to split the audio file into separate files each file have only instrument tune. But basically the output now is just a corrupted files which shouldn't be the case at all.

I have tried many files but didn't work.
anyone knows why is this happening ?

Comment: What is your desired result? Please provide more details so we know what you want to do with this file.

Comment: the desired result i'm expecting is to split the audio file into separate files each file have only instrument tune.
but basically the output now is just a corrupted files which shouldn't be the case at all.